# Issue with support:design:23.0.0 and setOnTabSelectedListener with tab custom view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-design-library

With android.support:design:23.0.0. setOnTabSelectedListener is triggered only when i click on a tab but it doesn't get triggered with the ViewPager when i swipe it.

let me give you an example:

```
 public void setTabs() {

    tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }

  tabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(pager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            super.onTabSelected(tab);
            tabPosition = tab.getPosition();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+tabPosition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (tabPosition == 0) {

            }
            if (tabPosition == 1) {

            }
            if (tabPosition == 2) {

            }
            if (tabPosition == 3) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
```

getTabView method from pagerAdapter:

```
 public View getTabView(int position) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        // TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tabTextView);
        // tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tabImageView);
        img.setImageResource(imageResId[position]);

        return v;
    }
```

Toast isn't showing on swipe, only on click. It works fine with the old 22.2.1 revison. What is causing this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You need to report this issue to code.google.com

Answer (score 2):

you are right. I faced the same exact problem and sometimes tabs even don't get triggered when you click on the tabs. I fixed it by using both :
  public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
   and public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) methods. Then I switched back to android.support:design:22.2.1 library to have it works cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now in new version (23.0.1).